# How to update decimal numbers in Interactive SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update, decimal, sqldatatypes

I need to update a field which is "1,413,083,211" to "1,413,886,215"

I managed decimal numbers which is like 1321,23 with DECIMAL function. But there is more decimal points.

So what is the right way/code to update this decimal number?

Comment: what is the data type of the column? is it money type?

Comment: This column holds time.
In user interface I wrote a time like 10/08/2014 23:52 and the system convert this time value to 1,413,886,215 format and writing to database.

Comment: Replace(@val,',','') and then cast as int and update

Comment: Hi @Rajesh,
Can u show me with an example please?
my query is like;
`update tblpatient
set autodisc='1,413,083,954'
where nunit='bap' and ptname like 'ba%' and dischargetime='0'
`

Comment: assuming microsoft sql server, try, update tblpatient set autodisc=cast(REPLACE('1,413,083,954',',','') as int)where nunit='bap' and ptname like 'ba%' and dischargetime='0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a field - you can update it like any other field:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_decimal_field = 1413886215
WHERE  my_decimal_field = 1413083211
```

Comment: If I ll sent this query I ll get this error:
"Cannot convert 1,413,886,215 to a int."

Comment: What's the datatype of the field, and what RDBMS are you using?